# how to find in which table a particular data exist

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 5 tables as follows LEDProducts,ElectricalProduts, AudioProducts, VideoProducts and Structure Products. The columns in each table are as follows MaterialName, PartNo,UOM . i want to find in which table  a particular PartNo exist. Which is the fastest way to find?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

In the Query, give the column name you want in where clause. It will show you both the column name and as well as table name.

`SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'PartNo'`

Comment: This way you get all the tables containing 'PartNo' columns. Next step is to loop through all the tables and check if it contains that particular PartNo.

Comment: Other tables are also have the column PartNo, but i want to know only in which the above mentioned table the partno exist. Not from all

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

`SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'PartNo' and table_name IN ('LEDProducts','ElectricalProduts', 'AudioProducts', 'VideoProducts', 'Structure Products'`

It will selects the given column name with a table names of "LEDProducts","ElectricalProduts", "AudioProducts", "VideoProducts" and "Structure Products"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union:

```
Select TabName from (
  select 'LEDProducts' as TabName, PartNo from LEDProducts
    union
  select 'ElectricalProduts', PartNo from ElectricalProduts 
    union 
  select 'AudioProducts', PartNo from AudioProducts
    union
  select 'VideoProducts',  PartNo from VideoProducts
    union
  select 'StructureProducts',  PartNo from StructureProducts
) AllProducts
where PartNo = 123
```

If you are running queries like this often it may make sense to create a view for `AllProducts`

```
create view AllProducts as
  select 'LEDProducts' as TabName, MaterialName, PartNo,UOM from LEDProducts
    union
  select 'ElectricalProduts', MaterialName, PartNo,UOM from ElectricalProduts 
    union 
  select 'AudioProducts', MaterialName, PartNo,UOM from AudioProducts
    union
  select 'VideoProducts',  MaterialName, PartNo,UOM from VideoProducts
    union
  select 'StructureProducts',  MaterialName, PartNo,UOM from StructureProducts
```

Then you can use queries like:

```
select TabName from AllProducts where PartNo = 123
```

Comment: i want to know the table name only

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you should consider creating a partno_lookup table that has columns (partno, table_id, tablename).  Then copy all your part numbers & record ids into this table.  Depending on your needs, the copy could be done on each insert/update/delete or it could be a periodic bulk transfer.

With this solution you use more space, but you find the table containing the partno with only one query that can be optimized.  It will be faster than performing up to 5 queries, using cursors, or unions, which will all typically be much slower.